# Sum of a divergent series depends on the way how one performs the summation

Tags: divergent-series

Can some one explain the following sentence regarding summation of divergent series?

$\text{Sum of a divergent series depends on the way how one performs the summation}.$

What does mean it?

Can someone explain it by giving an example?

Thanks

Comment: You might like to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: The series
$$
1 - 1 + 1 - 1 +\ldots
$$
comes to my mind. You can see it as $(1-1) + (1+1) + \dots$ or $1 - (1-1)  - (1-1) \ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n;$$
depending on how one groups the terms, one has $0$ or $1$:

$$
1 + (-1 + 1) + (-1 + 1) \to 1\\
(1 - 1) + (1 -1) \cdots \to 0
.$$

Comment: can you explain it in terms of language ? Because you took one convergent series. But I said for divergent series

Comment: With infinite series that diverge like above we can rearrange the terms in groupings that yield two values - each grouping is equally valid, but equally meaningless to the value of the sum - since it is not a convergent sum.Please take a look at the link by @trancelocation .

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR If by "divergent" series you mean a sum of **positive** terms that does **not** have a finite sum, then the statement you quote is **not** true. Please read the Riemann series theorem Wikipedia article for details.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is possible that the theorem you are alluding to concerns, not *divergent* series, but rather *conditionally convergent* series.

If you insist on 'divergent', meaning 'non-convergent', then there are different ways a series may fail to converge; for some the statement given holds, for others not.  Here the comment by @Somos is pertinent.